# Outlook Web AddIn works perfectly on Office 365 Online but fails on On-Premise Exchange Server 2013

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I have developed a Outlook Web Add-in. It appears in the context of **MessageReadCommandSurface** and **AppointmentReadCommandSurface**. It works perfectly fine as expected for Office 365 accounts when accessed from Web browser, Outlook for Mac and Windows. 
However, the same **add-in does not appear in the MessageReadCommandSurface mode when installed in the Exchange Server 2013**. 
I have validated my XML using the [Office App Compatibility Kit here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46831)

I have no errors except the high resolution icon needed.

I am not posting my manifest file since it is too big.

Can somebody shred some light on what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share which clients you were using to connect to Exchange 2013?

Comment: Thank you for the response Outlook Team. I managed to resolve the issue. Posting here so that anybody else facing similar issue may use it. I have version overrides in my XML manifest. In the VersionOverides I had added the rule for Message and Appointment which worked well for Office 365 online. But I had the rule set for the Appointment in the default XML manifest. Looks like Exchange 2013 picked up the default rules and not the overrides. Once I added the rule in default manifest, it worked for Message as well.

Comment: That's right. Exchange 2013, and the OWA that comes with Exchange 2013 does not read the version overrides section. If, on the other hand, you are using Windows Desktop Outlook 2016 to connect to Exchange 2013, the MessageReadCommandSurface should show up in desktop Outlook.

Comment: @BalajiBirajdar can you please update the same solution as answer so that others can understand it better.